# .htaccess rule to catch http and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We recently changed domains and are using this in our .htaccess file to rewrite the urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I realized earlier that the old site was using https:// so, that's where all the old links go. How can I make this rule rewrite for https AND http?

I tried using OR with another line with ${HTTPS_HOST} but that didn't work.

-----EDIT-----

To clarify, here is the result I want

http://oldsite.com/* --> https://newsite.com/*

https://oldsite.com/* --> https://newsite.com/*

Right now, http://oldsite.com/* redirects to https://newsite.com/*, BUT

https://oldsite.com/* redirects to the main site on the server. Just hitting the same IP from 4403, and not redirecting to newsite.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: With this, https: urls go to the site (on the server where this .htaccess file is located) that is secured with SSL, which is not the site I want to redirect to. old.com is setup as an addon domain to other.com. So https://old.com is going to other.com, not new.com

Comment: OK then can you clarify what you mean by **How can I make this rule rewrite for https AND http?**

Comment: If you remove this htaccess and then visit in `https://oldsite.com/*` Chrome dev tool what do you see?